# Share variables across different classes Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I want to have one main class and inside it some variables that I want to call inside other classes. For example:

```
class AwsS3Initalization
  attr_reader :resource, :client

  def initialize resource, client
    @resource = resource
    @client = client
    # Where do I define those variables below? I think this is not the right place to put them
    @resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'region', access_key_id: 'my-key', secret_access_key: 'secret-key')
    @client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'region', access_key_id: 'my-key', secret_access_key: 'secret-key')
  end
end
```

I want to be able to call @resource and @client in other classes that I have. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to inherit other classes from `AwsS3Initalization` like:

```
class Foo < AwsS3Initalization
end

class Bar < AwsS3Initalization
end
```

Then you will be able to access all the variables from parent class into subclasses.

**UPDATE**

```
class AwsS3Initialization
  ACCESS_KEY = <read-from-yml>
  SECRET_KEY = <read-from-yml>

  def self.resource
    Aws::S3::Resource.new(...)
  end

  def self.client
    Aws::S3::Client.new(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know maybe what is the best place to define resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new('') and client = Aws::S3::Client.new('')?

Comment: To my best knowledge, the best place to keep your secret keys is a yml file inside `config` folder and to define a class using them is inside `initializers`.

Comment: Are you sure you need to create an instance of `AwsS3Initalization`? I mean are there multiple access keys for this in your app?

Comment: Maybe the class name I have chosen is not the best. I am ok with defining keys, I just need to call variables client and resource across classes. For example, I don't want to define resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'region', access_key_id: 'my-key', secret_access_key: 'secret-key') in another class again. So I was not sure if the way I did it inside initialize method was the best way to define them.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer and see if that helps?

Comment: This way you can just call `AwsS3Initialization.resource` and `AwsS3Initialization.client` inside your app.

Comment: Perhaps you can make class methods for `access_key` and `secret_key` too. That way, you can write the logic to read from yml inside that method.

Comment: Ok I will try. Do you know maybe if I should put some of the methods as private in AwsS3Initialization class like that or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Not needed i guess.